# How can I get the text from PDF page?

Tags: objective-c, pdf

How can I get the text from PDF page in Objective-C?

Comment: Duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287635/how-to-parse-pdf-in-objective-c-for-ipad

Comment: So where is the answer there?

Comment: @Avram that question has nothing to do with text extraction from PDF

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong link. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960195/extracting-pdf-text-in-objective-c

Comment: I see. Still "solution" represented there is crappy at best. It will not work for any nontrivial PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for iOS or OS X?  If for OS X you could simply create an Automator workflow to extract the text, and call that workflow from your app.  Automator has a PDF action "Extract PDF Text" for exactly this purpose.  The [Automator framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/AutomatorReference/_index.html) allows calling of automator actions from your app. And some sample code can be found at http://rogueamoeba.com/utm/2005/06/03/  (note that the actual code has been updated to make use of the Automator framework).

Comment: Then as mentioned below you'll need to use a 3rd party library or develop your own.  Besides the ones already mentioned you might check out https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/ (searching capability, but can pull out text as well) and https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit (free version as well as paid versions available)

Answer (score 5):

First of all - give up on any "quick & dirty" solution for parsing PDF - it will fail miserably. My colleague spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem correctly in iOS. His top 3 (by quality, descending) options:

1. muPDF (http://www.mupdf.com/) Great library - it will do extraction fine. It is licensed under GPL though which is a show stopper for our proprietary application.
2. Homemade solution based on the [CGPDFScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFScanner/Reference/reference.html). You can find a short description of how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378933/644579) . The main problem of this approach is SDK itself - Apple's API for PDF is severely (and deliberately I suspect) limited. For example you'll have to lay out extracted text blocks in 2D space because PDF doesn't guarantee that order of drawing  matches text flow and iOS SDK is not a bit helpful here.
3. Poppler (http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) is OK but for the text extraction it is a rough equivalent of the second option (with tons of additional dependencies).

There can be more options with Mac OS X but I don't know them.

Comment: muPDF is only for viewing.