# How to Convert pdf page to text file in ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdf

Can you please help me to convert the particular PDF file page to a text file or provide me link to edit the pdf file iOS application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the text from PDF page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427634/how-can-i-get-the-text-from-pdf-page)

Comment: sorry dude i dont want the text from PDF page.i need a seperate text file.

Comment: Dude it give you text from pdf file and you need to write it down on text file using simple I/O operation of string read and write. I have to understand what you need initially without depending on 3rd party library or API.

Comment: actually my requirement is to edit the PDF file is there any solution to ake a user to edit his pdf file???

Answer (score 1):

When you load a custom document type (doc, ppt, pdf, etc) into a UIWebView, the webview returns a nil HTML string, even via javascript. There's a few suggestions for extracting PDF text [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960195/extracting-pdf-text-in-objective-c).

But turning the string back into a PDF is different. If you want to retain the formatting of the original PDF, I'm rather sure that's impossible because NSAttributedString on iOS doesn't do much. But this will work for plain text or NSAttributedString, if its possible:

```
NSData *PDFDataFromString(NSString *str) {
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];

//Create an NSAttributedString for CoreText. If you find a way to translate
//PDF into an NSAttributedString, you can skip this step and simply use an
//NSAttributedString for this method's argument.

NSAttributedString* string = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str] autorelease];

//612 and 792 are the dimensions of the paper in pixels. (8.5" x 11")
CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 612, 792);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef) string);
CGSize requiredSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [string length]), NULL, CGSizeMake(paperRect.size.width - 144, 1e40), NULL);

//Subtract the top and bottom margins (72 and 72), so they aren't factored in page count calculations.
NSUInteger pageCount = ceill(requiredSize.height / (paperRect.size.height - 144));
CFIndex resumePageIndex = 0;
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, paperRect, nil);

for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) 
{

//After calculating the required number of pages, break up the string and
//draw them into sequential pages.

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState (currentContext);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //72 and 72 are the X and Y margins of the page in pixels.
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, CGRectInset(paperRect, 72.0, 72.0));

    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(resumePageIndex, 0), framePath, NULL);
    resumePageIndex += CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frameRef).length;
    CGPathRelease(framePath);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, paperRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
    CFRelease(frameRef);    
    CGContextRestoreGState (currentContext);
}
CFRelease(framesetter);
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
return data;
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: thanx for the reply dude can u explain what does the result it produce to me???

Comment: will it give me a seperate text file or any other???

Comment: i have integrated the files to my application from link which u have posted but i'm getting some errors in that may be becoz of the xcode version prob does it work in version 4.2 ???

Comment: @J.Chandrasekhar Reddy dude after many searched your question i got this answer i found this above solution and it's worked if you are done this very well then please explain in given your answer because that will be helpful for other thanks

Comment: im getting some errors dude and it is unpredictable...